# How to add build.gradle on existing Android app on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I have existing Android app on my Eclipse Android Studio for Mac, and I will be using 
[chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/QuickStart-Stock)

and the installation of this needs **Adding Library as a Dependency** using **build.gradle** but I don't have build.gradle on my project. How can I add this gradle file so I can use ActionBar-PullToRefresh.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution I follow the **Export from Eclipse** on this thread [Migrating from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without ADT (and Eclipse as well) just add [drop-in template](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle/docs/android/build.gradle) and get your gradle build passing first.